# Search Engines indexing of CV profile on Stack Overflow Careers doesn't work

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

One month ago I made my profile public and enabled search engines in the settings of my Stack Overflow Careers profile. Now I check the status and see that Google didn't index my profile on Stack Overflow Careers.

There is no such issue on other CV/Careers social networks sites, which were also previously closed for indexing and reopened at the same day as SO Careers profile.
Why Google doesn't index my Stack Overflow Careers profile?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We don't currently publish CVs in our sitemap so it can take a while for Google to get around to indexing CVs. I'm looking into doing that right now.

In the meantime you could link your SO profile to your CV using [Edit Profile & Settings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/current). Scroll down to the 'Careers' section and check the 'Show CV link on my profile'.

[image: CV Settings]

Why does this work? Well we have questions in our sitemap and user profiles are linked from questions. If you CV is linked from here also then Google will pick it up a little quicker!

**UPDATE**: I've added public, indexable CVs to the sitemap hopefully they'll become more visible over the coming days.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer. Could you, please, provide a link to the site map page? I can't find it neither in header, not in footer of the SO site.

Comment: @MikeB. Our sitemap is several GB in size so we restrict it to access by search engines only to minimise bandwidth costs. There's nothing particularly special about it; it just lists all the URLs we'd *like* search engines to index. What they *actually* index is up to them.

Comment: The search engines setting referred to in the question appears to have gone away since 2016. If the "Always visible" setting is enabled, does that mean a developer story/CV is visible to search engines?